# Querying Composite Key inner Entity properties

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one entity called ProductTemplate with the following hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="none">
    <class name="com.stackoverflow.ProductTemplateImpl" table="PRODUCT_TEMPLATE" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <composite-id name="productTemplatePk" class="com.stackoverflow.product.ProductTemplatePK">
            <key-property name="templateType" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="TEMPLATE_ID" sql-type="VARCHAR2(255)" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-many-to-one name="product" class="com.stackoverflow.ProductImpl" >
                <column name="PROD_ID"/>
            </key-many-to-one>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

where ProductTemplatePK is a normal java Primary key class.

and another entity called Product with the following hibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="none">
    <class name="com.stackoverflow.ProductImpl" table="PRODUCT" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="PROD_ID" sql-type="VARCHAR2(255)"/>
            <generator class="assigned">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
                     <column name="PROD_STATE" not-null="true" unique="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="nameEn" type="java.lang.String">
                     <column name="PROD_NAME_EN" not-null="true" unique="false"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now if I tried to retrieve all productTemplates based on the productId I can do it using the following hibernate criteria:

```
Criteria productTemplateCriteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ProductTemplate.class);
productTemplateCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("productTemplatePk.product.id", "1"));
```

but I don't know how to retrieve those templates based on the product.nameEn as the following code:

```
Criteria productTemplateCriteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ProductTemplate.class);
productTemplateCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("productTemplatePk.product.nameEn", "Ali"));
```

generates the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: productTemplatePk.product.nameEn of: com.stackoverflow.ProductTemplateImpl.

so how can I query an entity property that is mapped as part of a composite primary key ?

Answer (score 1):

I manged to solve this by simple HQL query as I didn't find any way to do it using hibernate API

**this is the HQL query I used:**

```
 from com.stackoverflow.ProductTemplateImpl productTemplate
where productTemplate.productTemplatePk.product.state not in (:productStates)
```

**But I'm still interested to know if there is any Hibernate API combination that can do it.**

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get deeper than 2 levels except for ids when specifying property names in criteria. Try using explicit join with alias:

```
Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(ProductTemplate.class);
crit.addAlias("productTemplatePk.product","p")
    .add(Restrictions.in("p.nameEn", "Ali"));
```

Comment: actually this generates the following sql query:
'Hibernate: 
select this_.TEMPLATE_ID as TEMPLATE1_62_0_, ... 
  from PRODUCT_TEMPLATE this_ 
 where product1_.PROD_STATE in (?)'

**which generates the following exception:** 
ORA-00904: "PRODUCT1_"."PROD_STATE": invalid identifier

Comment: and this is the same SQL that is being generated if I tried to use
createCriteria instead of createAlias.

Comment: Not sure why it would refer 'PROD_STATE' in `in` clause. Can you post exact code that caused it? In any case, you would need to do some experimentation. It's just an idea.

Comment: sorry but this was my condition part I have just tried to simplify the question.
this is actually the code that generates the above sql:

Criteria productTemplateCriteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ProductTemplate.class); productTemplateCriteria.createAlias("productTemplatePk.product", "product") .add(Restrictions.in("product.state", filter.getProductStates()));

Comment: I suggest that you simplify query initially. Replace `in` with `eq` for test. Also give it different alias to make sure that it's different from property name.

Comment: the same; it generates the following sql query: 'Hibernate: select this_.TEMPLATE_ID as TEMPLATE1_62_0_, ... from PRODUCT_TEMPLATE this_ where p1_.PROD_STATE = ?'